# XPATH expression to sort and return matching items last

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML that is created in a sort order determined by its creator which puts some types of items at the beginning of the list, I need to present these at the bottom.

The data has items for TypeID 4 and 6 before all others, I need them after all others.  Example XML is...

```
<root>
  <Item>
    <TypeID>4</TypeID>
    <Name>Item 4-1</Name>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <TypeID>4</TypeID>
    <Name>Item 4-2</Name>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <TypeID>6</TypeID>
    <Name>Item 6-1</Name>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <TypeID>2</TypeID>
    <Name>Item 2-1</Name>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <TypeID>10</TypeID>
    <Name>Item 10-1</Name>
  </Item>
</root>
```

Given the XSTL...

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/Item">
  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I need to return the results...

```
Item 2-1
Item 10-1
Item 4-1
Item 4-2
Item 6-1
```

I'm struggling with and XPATH expression to use in xsl:sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do simply:

```
<xsl:sort select="TypeID=4 or TypeID=6"/>
```

This returns "true" for the items you want to be last - and "true" comes after "false" in alphabetical order.

Or do the same thing with numbers:

```
<xsl:sort select="number(TypeID=4 or TypeID=6)" data-type="number"/>
```

Or avoid sort altogether and do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Item[not(TypeID=4 or TypeID=6)]/Name"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Item[TypeID=4 or TypeID=6]/Name"/>
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid 2 selects as I need to know the position and wanted to avoid an 'offset' counting how many were in the first results for the second.  Thanks for the tips on boolean sorting order.

Comment: Do these "tips" not answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I have subsequently tested your suggestions and they work.  Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very elegant, and I know there will never be more than 500 results, so I have found this to work..

```
<xsl:sort select="position() + (count(current()[TypeID = 4 or TypeID = 6]/TypeID) * 500)" data-type="number"/>
```